# JavaMail: Socket read timeout

Tags: java, sockets, timeout, jakarta-mail

I'm using JavaMail and I want it to work through proxy for every threads (I have multithreading application). I'm using SMTPTransport.connect(Socket socket) for this.

Here is socket initialization:

```
socket = new Socket();
socket.setSoTimeout(10000);
socket.connect(new InetSocketAddress(smtpHost, smtpPort));
```

Here is SMTPTransport call:

```
SMTPTransport transport = null;
try
    {
     transport = (SMTPTransport) mail.getTransport("smtp");
     transport.connect(socket);
     System.out.println("ok");
```

And so on. But I this error happens:

> DEBUG: JavaMail version 1.4.4 DEBUG: successfully loaded resource:
>   /META-INF/javamail.default.providers DEBUG: Tables of loaded providers
>   DEBUG: Providers Listed By Class Name:
>   {com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSSLTransport=javax.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtps,com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSSLTransport,Sun
>   Microsystems, Inc],
>   com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport=javax.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtp,com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport,Sun
>   Microsystems, Inc],
>   com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPSSLStore=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,imaps,com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPSSLStore,Sun
>   Microsystems, Inc],
>   com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3SSLStore=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,pop3s,com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3SSLStore,Sun
>   Microsystems, Inc],
>   com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPStore=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,imap,com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPStore,Sun
>   Microsystems, Inc],
>   com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3Store=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,pop3,com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3Store,Sun
>   Microsystems, Inc]} DEBUG: Providers Listed By Protocol:
>   {imaps=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,imaps,com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPSSLStore,Sun
>   Microsystems, Inc],
>   imap=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,imap,com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPStore,Sun
>   Microsystems, Inc],
>   smtps=javax.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtps,com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSSLTransport,Sun
>   Microsystems, Inc],
>   pop3=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,pop3,com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3Store,Sun
>   Microsystems, Inc],
>   pop3s=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,pop3s,com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3SSLStore,Sun
>   Microsystems, Inc],
>   smtp=javax.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtp,com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport,Sun
>   Microsystems, Inc]} DEBUG: successfully loaded resource:
>   /META-INF/javamail.default.address.map DEBUG: getProvider() returning
>   javax.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtp,com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport,Sun
>   Microsystems, Inc] DEBUG SMTP: useEhlo true, useAuth true DEBUG SMTP:
>   useEhlo true, useAuth true DEBUG SMTP: starting protocol to host
>   "smtp.googlemail.com", port 465 DEBUG SMTP: exception reading
>   response: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out Exception
>   reading response javax.mail.MessagingException: Exception reading
>   response;   nested exception is:  java.net.SocketTimeoutException:
>   Read timed out    at
>   com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.readServerResponse(SMTPTransport.java:2153)
>     at
>   com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.openServer(SMTPTransport.java:1956)
>     at
>   com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.protocolConnect(SMTPTransport.java:636)
>     at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:317)     at
>   javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:176)  at
>   javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:125)  at
>   com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.connect(SMTPTransport.java:274)   at
>   lsmtpc.CheckAccount.run(CheckAccount.java:203)    at
>   java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
>     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
>     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722) Caused by:
>   java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out   at
>   java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)     at
>   java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:150)   at
>   java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:121)   at
>   com.sun.mail.util.TraceInputStream.read(TraceInputStream.java:110)    at
>   java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:235)    at
>   java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:254)    at
>   com.sun.mail.util.LineInputStream.readLine(LineInputStream.java:89)
>     at
>   com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.readServerResponse(SMTPTransport.java:2131)
>     ... 13 more

So as I see JavaMail can't read from socket. So what am I doing wrong? If I try to use transport.connect() method without using Socket in constructor all works perfectly and smtpHost/smtpPort are accessible from the telnet and I have no any firewalls/antiviruses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the documentation for com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport:

> In general, applications should not need to use the classes in this
>   package directly. Instead, they should use the APIs defined by
>   javax.mail package (and subpackages). Applications should never
>   construct instances of SMTPTransport directly. Instead, they should
>   use the Session method getTransport to acquire an appropriate
>   Transport object.
>
> WARNING: The APIs unique to this package should be considered
>   EXPERIMENTAL. They may be changed in the future in ways that are
>   incompatible with applications using the current APIs.

JavaMail tutorial: http://java.sun.com/developer/onlineTraining/JavaMail/contents.html

Could be you are not passing authentication information. Could be you are connecting to a secured host using a plain socket. You might want to read the tutorial linked for the best way to use JavaMail.

Comment: Yes but how to use proxy for javamail in another way? JM not have any proxy settings.

Comment: Also here is no any info about not using: http://javamail.kenai.com/nonav/javadocs/com/sun/mail/smtp/SMTPTransport.html So I can't understand why it can't read from socket.

Comment: You shouldn't have to do anything special to connect through a mail proxy, assuming it is setup properly. Aka, this is a network configuration issue, not a software coding one - http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/faq-135477.html#proxy.

Comment: What do you mean? I have a large list of remote socks (which is not installed on my local pc) and I need to use it for connection to some my email accounts through smtp.